# Why I can't translated message with id in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, translate

I am newbie for Symfony. I am trying translate some message for some languages. I can do it with message like 'Syfony is great'. Now I want to do for id like id='hello_message'.

My index.twig at below

```
{% block body %}
<p>{{'hello_message'|trans}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My xliff file at below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<file source-language="en" target-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="hello_message">
            <source>hello.message</source>
            <target>Symfony Harika!</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
</file>
```

And my default controller just call twig

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *source* that get translated, not the id:

```
{% block body %}
<p>{{'hello.message'|trans}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Also, remember to clear the cache if you're in prod environment.

Comment: why when I use <source>hello.message</source> doesn't work? I want to source key use more than one. I did this already.

Comment: With hello.message as source, you should  use {{ 'hello.message' | trans }}. Also, check that your translation files are located and named properly: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations

Comment: It could be that symfony it's not finding the translation file.

Comment: I dont think so, because if I use <source>Symdony is great</source> its work. When I use <source>hello.message</source> doesnt work

Comment: There's only one translation file and you cleared the cache after modifying the file, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112870/discussion-between-kerim-and-devilcius).

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 3 you use attribute resname. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file original="global" datatype="plaintext" source-language="en" target-language="vi">
        <body>
            <!-- COMMONS -->
            <trans-unit id="common_say_hello" resname="common_say_hello">
                <source>Hello</source>
                <target>Xin chào</target>
            </trans-unit>            
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

---

{{ 'common_say_hello'|trans }}

Output
Xin chào